# Mousenter/mouseleave for nested divs causes Ffox misbehavior

Tags: jquery, html, nested, mouseenter, mouseleave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nested div weird mouseenter/mouseleave behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148820/nested-div-weird-mouseenter-mouseleave-behavior)

For [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XrKbk/12/) we want that when the mouse enters from below in pink innerDiv and leaves without entering into green outerDiv, the green outerDiv's mouseenter event is not triggered.

The expected behavior happens with Chrome and Opera but not with Ffox.

Below follow the console outputs of the jsfiddle code for each browser.

Chrome/Opera output (correct):

```
pink innerDiv mouseenter

pink innerDiv mouseleave
```

Ffox output:

```
pink innerDiv mouseenter

pink innerDiv mouseleave

left pink innerDiv but through green outerDiv

green outerDiv mouseenter
```

Any idea why Ffox misbehaves and how to code it so that Ffox gets it right?

JSFiddle code:

HTML:

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    Outer div text
    <div class="innerDiv">
        Inner div text
    </div>
</div>
```

​
CSS:

```
div.outerDiv {
       position: relative;
       height: 110px;
       cursor: auto;
       padding-top: 0;
       background-color: #00A300 !important;
       box-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFFFCC inset;
       color: #FFFFFF;
       display: block;
       float: left;
       font-family: 'Segoe UI Semilight','Open Sans',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
       font-size: 11pt;
       font-weight: 300;
       letter-spacing: 0.02em;
       line-height: 20px;
       margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
       overflow: hidden;
       text-decoration: none;
       width: 150px;
   }

   div.innerDiv{ position:absolute; 
       width: 100%; 
       bottom: 0;
    background-color: magenta;
   }​
```

Javascript:

```
$('div.outerDiv').on('mouseenter', function(){ console.log('green outerDiv mouseenter'); });

$('div.outerDiv').on('mouseleave', function(){ console.log('green outerDiv mouseeleave');     });


$('div.innerDiv').on('mouseenter', function(){ console.log('pink innerDiv mouseenter');     return false; });

$('div.innerDiv').on('mouseleave', function(){ 
    console.log('pink innerDiv mouseleave'); 
    if($('div.outerDiv').is(':hover')){
         console.log('left pink innerDiv but through green outerDiv');
        $('div.outerDiv').trigger('mouseenter');
    }
    return false;
});
```

​

Comment: behavior is as expected... will need to rethink your code. Also there is no `:hover` selector

Comment: This is a rephrasing of the post ["Nested div weird mouseenter/mouseleave behavior"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148820/nested-div-weird-mouseenter-mouseleave-behavior) which was originally poorly phrased.

Comment: @charlietfl Even though I've seen it, you are right: there is no `.is(':hover')` selector. But still, why do Chrome & Opera interpret it correctly and Ffox doesn't. Alternative structure ideas to overcome the problem?

Comment: @undefined I'd like to reopen this question so I can answer it. Also it would be more useful to mark the [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148820/nested-div-weird-mouseenter-mouseleave-behavior)  as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your HTML element structure, the pink div is actually covering the bottom part of the green div. Hence when the mouse enter pink div from the bottom, you cannot pretend it did not enter the green div. It did!

From DOM perspective, you cannot just assume the green div size is only as big as what's visible to your eye, but it also covers the area covered by the pink div.

In case of stacking elements, HTML spec divides the event handler into two phases: event capturing and bubbling. The order of which element's handler get fired first depend on what phase the event is registered for. I suggest either you re-organize your HTML elements so they don't overlap, and/or spend some time to learn javascript event bubbling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: gerrytan is right about the nesting issue. Add `.outerDiv {outline:4px solid red }
.innerDiv {outline:4px dotted blue }` to your fiddle, and you'll see it. You can't enter the pink one without entering the green (or exit).

Comment: I understand the DOM perspective and how event propagation works. The issue is that Chrome and Opera don't consider the mouse pointer doing a mouseenter in the green outerDiv when I leave the pink innerDiv. So  is Ffox more correct than Chrome and Opera?